# connecting twilio sip trunk to freeswitch

Tags: twilio, sip, freeswitch

i have been struggling to connect my freeswitch with twilio sip trunk, i can successful connect my freeswitch with signalwire without any problem, but following the same procedure for twilio seem not working.
i have set the sip trunk on twilio and i have created a credential(for the username & password)

and on my freeswitch, i have include the following IPs in autoload_configs/acl.conf.xml as follows:

```
<configuration name="acl.conf" description="Network Lists">
    <network-lists>
        <list name="domains" default="deny">
            <node type="allow" cidr="54.172.60.0/23"/>
            <node type="allow" cidr="54.171.127.192/26"/>
            <node type="allow" cidr="54.65.63.192/26"/>
            <node type="allow" cidr="54.169.127.128/26"/>
            <node type="allow" cidr="54.252.254.64/26"/>
            <node type="allow" cidr="177.71.206.192/26"/>
        </list>
    </network-lists>
</configuration>
```

and my gateway in sip_profiles looks like this

```
<include>
    <gateway name="TwilioConnect">
        <param name="username" value="username created from twilio credential"/>
        <param name="password" value="password created from twilio credential" />
        <param name="realm" value="sample.pstn.twilio.com"/>
        <param name="proxy" value="sample.pstn.twilio.com" />
        <param name="register" value="false"/>
    
    </gateway>
</include>
```

on my fs_cli, the sofia status has the following error

```
 omid::TwilioConnect    gateway    sip:username@sample.pstn.twilio.com  TRYING (retry: 24s)
```

thanks.